# NSMutableOrderedSet and NSNull behavior?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, syntax

I don't understand why I can't add many [NSNull null] to a NSMutableOrderedSet:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *set = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc]init];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        [set addObject: [NSNull null]];
    }

NSLog("SET COUNT : %d", set.count);
```

This Output :

```
SET COUNT : 1
```

And if I try it with a NSMutableArray it works just fine, I've read NSNull documentation (which is really short but didn't help) but it says:

```
"The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects"
```

and NSMutableOrderedSet documentation and it says it's an

```
"[...] ordered collection of distinct objects"
```

So if it's a collection why isn't it working ?

Thank you very much

Comment: It says "ordered collection of distinct objects". Probably [NSNull null] is not distinct object.

Comment: `[NSNull null]` returns a `singleton` object, which means that there is only 1 version, and it is reused multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSNull null]` always returns *the same object* (the singleton instance of `NSNull`).

```
NSObject *a = [NSNull null];
NSObject *b = [NSNull null];
// a == b
```

`NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet` are collections of *distinct objects*, therefore they can contain at most one instance of this "null object".

Comment: Ok thank you very much ! still 4 mins to accept your answer I will as soon as I can !

Answer (score 1):

`NSOrderedSet` and its subclass `NSMutableOrderedSet` cannot contain multiple copies of the same object. `NSNull` is a *singleton*, hence adding it to a set multiple times results in adding only a single copy.

If you would like to be able to add multiple copies to a set, use `NSCountedSet` instead:

```
NSCountedSet set = [NSCountedSet set];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    [set addObject: [NSNull null]];
}
NSLog(@"%ud", [set countForObject:[NSNull null]]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you're all right and I'm stupid -.-, btw is NSCountedSet ordered ?

Comment: @Clarisse No, it is not ordered - "The NSCountedSet class declares the programmatic interface to a mutable, **unordered** collection of indistinct objects."

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There should be an `NSMutableOrderedCountedSet` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question itself has answer. It says `"ordered collection of distinct objects"` and `"The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects"`.  `[NSNull null]` is not a distinct object, it has only one instance and hence the count says 1. You cannot add multiple `"null"` objects like this to an `NSMutableOrderedSet`.